# AdMob banner above Tabs in TabsActivity

Tags: android

I am trying to set the AdMob banner ABOVE the Tabs in a TabsActivity:

```
public class FundsReportTabsActivity extends TabsActivity {     

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AdView adView = new AdView(activity, AdSize.BANNER, AD_UNIT_ID);              

    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"               

    // Add the adView to it  
     getTabHost().addView(adView, 0, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice("E0154BC3F11C778234254195FA1164F");
    adRequest.setTesting(true);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

However, the banner does not appear, even though I have this logcat:

09-29 22:23:09.755: INFO/Ads(16158): onReceiveAd()

and don't see any related warning/error.

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your logcat for a warning or verbose saying no ads in inventory. Some times when you first sign up or are using admob it takes some time before the ads start appearing. Also make sure you have provided a linear layout for the ad. And if you watch the logcat file during the activity with the ad you will see a content containing items that pertain to the ad. I know i had trouble with admob at first. The same issue you are having. It just took some time.